# mysql through SSH tunnel fails because of localhost

Tags: linux, mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to a remote `MySQL` database running on `server1.com` on `localhost`.

I've executed this on my client server:

```
ssh user@server1.com -L 3306:localhost:3306
```

And are trying to connect on my client server with:

```
mysql -h localhost -u mysql-user -p
```

But are getting:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Googling a bit tells me `localhost` forces the `mysql` client to setup a `socket` which I don't want to do.

Trying to use:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u mysql-user -p
```

fails, because the remote server `server1.com` doesn't accepts connection to the `mysql` database via `127.0.0.1`, only `localhost`.

What to do?

I've tried `socket` forwarding like:

```
ssh -L /tmp/mysql.sock:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock user@server1.com
```

but fails (on the remote server) with:

```
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

I have checked that the local and remote server doesn't have `AllowTCPForwarding` and `PermitOpen` is not set.

Comment: I know this is marked as dublicate, but I cannot find an answer in the linked question.

Comment: `localhost` is a socket.  You need to use TCP/IP.  GRANT access and use an ip address, not localhost.